# How to avoid schoice questions to receive positive points when two options are selected (one of them right)?

Tags: r, r-exams

When using the `nops_eval` function in an exam with only `schoice` items (5 possible answers), we want the wrong answers to be evaluated like 1/n number of incorrect options. E.g. an item with 3 expoints with a wrong answer should receive: `1/-4 = -.25`. However, if a student answers two options in an exam:

[image]

It must not give any positive points... it is a `schoice` question, so it should evaluate as a wrong answer (i.e. `1/(-4)`) even if one of the answers is the right one.

The used options were:

```
eval_v1 <- nops_eval(register = "nops_eval/pauta_II.csv",
          solutions = "nops_eval/Ex_AEII_MTI_v1_.rds",
          scans = "nops_eval/nops_scan_20210120211740_v1.zip", language = "pt",
          eval = exams_eval(partial = T, negative = T, rule = "false"),
          dir = "eval",
          interactive = T)
```

If the argument `rule = "false2"` the final result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution... we should set `partial = F, negative = -.25`. With `partial = F`, we assure that only full right answers are accepted (as `schoice` presumes) and with `negative = -.25` we assure that all wrong answers are penalized with `-.25` times the `expoints` of each exercise.

Comment: I perfectly understand how it all may be clear to you. The purpose of stackoverflow is to preserve knowledge so that others may benefit. Please provide a little more details for future users to understand your solution. Finally, it is perfectly alright for you to accept your own answer as solution. Thanks.

Comment: I proceeded accordingly.